# Origin of "gimble", "brillig"

Tags: etymology

I just noticed that "gimble" and "brilig" show up well before, and always more than "jabberwocky"  in [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jabberwocky%2Cbrillig%2Cgimble&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjabberwocky%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrillig%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgimble%3B%2Cc0)

I thought that these words originated in the Jabberwocky poem ... but apparently not?

What is the deal with that?

Comment: Brillig shows up only after 1871, the year _Through the looking glass_ was published, so it may still be safe to assume that is where it originated. As for the few occurrences of _gimble_ before that, could they be misspellings of _gamble_ of _gimbal_?

Comment: *Gimble* is usually spelled [*gimbal*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gimbal) which is a particular form of mount or hinge.

Comment: 'gimble' is not the same word as 'gimbal'.   'gimble' is a verb, not "usually spelled 'gimbal'"

Comment: What I meant was that the early NGram finds are the alternative spelling of *gimbal*.

Comment: I guess that could be the case eh... though strange that they are just in that pre-jabberwock time!

Comment: Strange? Perhaps the improved spelling mirrors the broadcasting of the fact that 'gimble' is just nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jabberwocky%2Cbrillig%2Cgimble&year_start=1700&year_end=1870&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjabberwocky%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrillig%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgimble%3B%2Cc0) shows only those before 1871, the year *Through the looking glass* was published. There are only results for *gimble*. Let's click through and check some of the results in Google Books.

- .. or cap there stands up, perpendicularly, a piece (or other suitable metal) or fork, having two prongsj and between these prongs is hung, by two small screws, a gimble Ting, within which is suspended (also by two small screws) a small cup, ...
- suitable metal) or fork, having two prongs, and between these prongs is hung, by two small screws, a gimble ring, within which is suspended (also by two small screws) a small cup, the bottom consisting of agate (or other suitable substance).
- ... to be further understood, that I claim under this head the balancing of the stone by means of a gimble or universal joint, in the manner of the mariners' compass, or any modification thereof substantially the same in principle and results.
- To GIMBLE, r. n. To grin or smile. Norf. GIMLIN, s. [Kemelin, Chaucer, from Kem- men, Belg.] A large shallow tub, in which bacon is salted. Craven. GIMMACE, s. [Gimmer, Fenning. A piece of machinery.] A hinge. Somerset. Gimmers. Norf.
- Gimble David T. Porter, late Joseph Shannon John Fobes John Needham, late Christian Keisel, late Samuel Kinsey, late Joseph Shnyder George Weiser, late S.imuel Bloom Robert Kelly William Stephens Orange A. Lewis John Schall, late ...
- Was it fooleries, when, of a fine spring day, I'd pull up at the garden-gate to take a bunch of flowers to stick in my buttonhole, and get a smile from ye that seemed to gimble itself through and through my buzzum ! Was it fooleries^ when, on our .
- Gimble-eyed, gimbleid, adj. schielend. Giñbleting, f. wird von einem Anker gefagt, der fich um einen Schaft Girnbrack, dschim-krack, f, das Schlagen der Taschenuhr; ein gemeiner Handgriff; Gimlet-Girdle der Hang zu mechanischen Künsten ...
- As well might we try to gimble a hole to the globe's centre, and have a spy at its axle. However, as far as within the compass of our abilities to lay bare the machinery working the woof of the adventures, and pulling the strings of our puppets on ...
- ... gimble to hold the end of the latch ; ' *, small cleet of iron fixed on the long iron bar N, and intended to push the latch aside from the chin or staple ; *«, inclined plane which enables the latch to rise or fall in its movement going and coming; ...
- ... near to the top, united by a hoop, H. FF are two more longitudinal bars, which are placed immediately above the top ends of the vertical bars, G, and work on a gimble, J ; K is a small framework, which is attached to the gimble, J, and carries, ...
- .. Wm. Garden, Mr Garland, Mr Garrett, Richard Gibbins, Richard Gill, John Gimble, G. Gill, Thomas Gibbons, Samuel Gillard, John Goddard, J. Goldsworthy, Richard Gordon, John Gowen, John & Mary Gossard, George Grady, George Grance, ...
- It was only the civil Mr. Gimble, wanting to know what Mr. Blyth was searching for, and whether he could help him. Valentine mentioned the loss of the tube; and Mr. Gimble immediately volunteered to make one of pasteboard. “Ten thousand ...
- This is accomplished by having a " fork " with " two prongs " stand up " perpendicularly" from "the bottom of the brass (or other " suitable metallic) box;" "a gimble ring" is suspended by screws between the prongs, within which ring the agate cup ...
- There is also an advantage in the method of constructing the lamps and the gimble work. The apparatus is arranged for exhibiting three reflectors in a face of three glasses, coloured red, white, and green. With this is associated a fourth order, ...

So some of are a ring in several parts, others are types of joint or hinge, yet more are surnames and it's also dialect, to smile.

The OED says it's an altered form of gimmal, with alternate spellings: jemble, gimbol(e), (jimbol), gimball, gimbel, gimble, (jimble), gimbald, gymbal, gimbal.
Etymology:

Here's how Lewis Carroll's used it in a poem called Jabberwocky, in *Through the Looking Glass*:

> ''Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
> Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
> All mimsy were the borogoves,
> And the mome raths outgrabe.'

But he goes on to explain the meanings:

> And what's to "gyre" and to "gimble"?'
>
> 'To "gyre" is to go round and round like a gyroscope. To "gimble" is to make holes like a gimlet.'
>
> 'And "the wabe" is the grass-plot round a sun-dial, I suppose?' said Alice, surprised at her own ingenuity.
>
> 'Of course it is. It's called "wabe" you know, because it goes a long way before it, and a long way behind it —'
>
> 'And a long way beyond it on each side,' Alice added.

Comment: @oerkelens: At the bottom there's a list of links: "Search in Google Books:

1700 - 1843 1844 - 1843 1844 - 1850 1851 - 1861 1862 gimble English"